# error: expected primary-expression before ‘template’ with copy function of algorithm

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, c++11

I am getting error on ostream_iterator. I wanted to keep T as a template. But at that point it is giving error. Kindly help me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

int main(void){
int arr[] =  {2, 5, 7, 90, 70};
int *ptr = arr;
char* str = "mudit";
int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
cout.write (str, 5); 
cout << endl;
//printing the array in one line.
copy(arr,arr+n,template<class T> ostream_iterator<T>(cout, "\n")); //Getting 
//error at this line.
//cout << copy(arr, arr+n) << endl;
int x = 7;
//cout << "Searching " << x << " position is at : " << search(arr, n, 
sizeof(int), &x, compare) << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please attach relevant error message from the compiler output

Comment: As my edit that corrected formatting was rolled-back by the OP, I'd like to remind them of [the reasons why editing is a good thing and part of SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing).

Answer (score 1):

The following line is not valid `C++` simple as that.

`copy(arr,arr+n,template<class T> ostream_iterator<T>(cout, "\n"));`

All compilers will complain with something like the following:

```
error: expected an expression
         template <class T> ostream_iterator<T>(cout, "\n"));
```

or

```
error: a template declaration cannot appear at block scope
        template <class T> ostream_iterator<T>(cout, "\n"));
```

You already know the type of the `ostream_iterator` you need to use, so why not using the following?

```
  // printing the array in one line.
  copy(arr, arr + n, ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
```

Note that I have removed the `\n` since the comment says you want to print all in one line.

You can templatize it creating a function like

```
template< typename T,typename Iterator>
void mycopy_ostream_iterator(Iterator start, Iterator end){
  copy(start, end, ostream_iterator<T>(cout, " "));  // Getting
}
```

and use it then as follows (note that the type of Iter can be deduced by the compiler)

```
mycopy_ostream_iterator<int>(arr, arr + n);
```

Comment: `T` can even be deduced from `Iterator`.

Comment: `T` is not needed at all. `copy(start, end, ostream_iterator <decltype(*start)>(cout, " ")); `

Comment: @DavideSpataro Thanx for helping out. basically I wanted to print array in one line. like we do in python. But I was wondering why can't we apply template along with ostream_iterator itself? Any specific reason for that???

Answer (score 0):

You should pass `ostream_interator` into sopy function in this way:

```
 copy(arr, arr + n, ostream_iterator<int>(cout, "\n"));
```

Comment: This I know. I was basically looking for template version. Davide responded to that.